# Apache Nifi: Resource directory paths are malformed: docs

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I'm getting "Resource directory paths are malformed" from the integrated NIFI webserver jetty. Jar exists and this is the content:

```
/jhub/_prod/server_global_unifieddata_nifi_daemon/storage/work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-docs-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
css/
images/
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/classes/
WEB-INF/classes/org/
WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/
WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/nifi/
WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/nifi/web/
WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/nifi/web/docs/
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/
WEB-INF/jsp/
js/
css/component-usage.css
css/main.css
images/bgHeader.png
images/bgTableHeader.png
images/bgBannerFoot.png
WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/nifi/web/docs/DocumentationController.class
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/NOTICE
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/LICENSE
WEB-INF/web.xml
WEB-INF/jsp/no-documentation-found.jsp
WEB-INF/jsp/documentation.jsp
js/application.js
META-INF/maven/org.apache.nifi/nifi-web-docs/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/org.apache.nifi/nifi-web-docs/pom.properties
```

And this is the message from the log:

```
==> nifi-app_2016-11-17_13.0.log <==
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:146) ~[nifi-runtime-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:243) ~[nifi-runtime-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource directory paths are malformed: docs
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.createDocsWebApp(JettyServer.java:540) ~[nifi-jetty-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.loadWars(JettyServer.java:321) ~[nifi-jetty-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.<init>(JettyServer.java:144) ~[nifi-jetty-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Can I have any pointer to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have a [`docs` directory](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.0.0/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-web/nifi-jetty/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/web/server/JettyServer.java#L511)?

Comment: no. Where is it  supposed to be ?

Comment: You got it man, a directory was missing! Thanks so much. Post this solution as answer to get more reputation.

Comment: I don't need the reputation.  Feel free to post the details on how to solve it as an answer yourself.  (a common, and allowed, practice here)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I created the missing folder into the nifi working directory.

"Resource directory paths are malformed" in this case means "Folder not found"